# Loop to copy and paste if activecell is not 0

Tags: vba, excel

i have been working on this code and my goal is to do a loop (starting from cell N5) until the last non empty cell on this column. The loop should check if the activecell is 0 or not, if its 0, just go to the cell bellow and if not it should copy and paste its value on the same row on column F. I wrote this but there is something wrong, could you please help me? Thank you!

```
Sub inserir_offshore1()

    Do Until x = 50
        Worksheets("Sistema Duda").Range("f5").Activate
        If ActiveCell <> 0 Then ActiveCell.Copy
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -8).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            x = x + 1
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveCell.Offset(0, -8)` you start in column F then try to go 8 columns left...impossible. And you always select `F5` again each iteration of loop.

Comment: @ScottCraner Suggest it in Meta.

Answer (score 2):

This code will do what you are looking for much more effectively.

```
Sub inserir_offshore1()

Dim LastRow as Long, ws as Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Sistema Duda")
LastRow = ws.Range("N" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 5 to LastRow
    If ws.Range("N" & x).Value <> 0 Then
        ws.Range("N" & x).Copy
        ws.Range("F" & x).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: You can't offset 8 columns to the left of `F` XD

Comment: Oh. That's what you meant. Edit: well, OP did specify column N XD

Answer (score 2):

With just pasting value consider assigning the values directly.

```
Sub inserir_offshore1()
Dim cel As Range
With Worksheets("Sistema Duda")
    For Each cel In .Range("N5", .Range("N" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If cel <> 0 Then
            cel.Offset(0, -8) = cel.value
        End If
    Next cel
End With

End Sub
```